# PgAdmin3 1.20 version for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin, ubuntu-16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and downloaded PgAdmin3 1.22.1 version. This version is not compatable with one of my postgresql database. I got error:
An error has occurred:

```
11:32:25: Error: ERROR:  function pg_get_function_result(oid) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pr.oid, pr.xmin, pr.*, pg_get_function_result(pr.oid)...
                                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So I need to downgrade my PgAdmin.I can't any information is it possible to to for Ubuntu 16.04 and how. Help me

Comment: Wow. That database must be PostgreSQL 8.3 or older ...

Comment: Yes, server PostgreSQL database version - 8.3

Comment: Have you done it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am working on

```
root@mwalko-X58A-UD3R:/home/mwalko/Downloads# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

and this is more like advise than tutorial.
You can install pgAdmin3 in version 1.20.x it still working with PostgreSQL 8.3. 
Install libgtk2.0-dev, libxml2-dev, libxslt-dev and wxGTK-2.8.12 (not in repo). Then download pgAdmin3 1.20.x and run dpkg -i pgadmin3.deb probably it will throw warnings like:

```
dpkg: warning: downgrading pgadmin3 from 1.22.0-1 to 1.20.0~beta2-1build1
```

or even an error but it works. 
@Edit it is much easier to upgrade postgreSQL version than trying to install that dinosaur